# Will homeless spiders found a new den or just sit forever?

Tags: dont-starve

When I was playing today, lightning struck in a dense forest full of spider dens. I ended up with a bunch of silk and dead butterflies on the ground, a ton of burnt trees, and a number of spiders sleeping out in the open because they have no home. Unfortunately, I died a few nights later; would they have eventually founded a new home? If not, would they have despawned, or would that be the forest of sleeping spiders until I managed to kill them all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Homeless spiders (whose den has been destroyed or who were spawned by a queen) will wander around during the night and sleep during the day. They will not enter another nest.

Comment: Forever until killed?

Comment: @Yamikuronue: as far as I can tell, yes.